# Allow a global variable modified in one class to be read by another class

Tags: python, luigi

I've inherited a series of luigi tasks in a python script, and I am attempting to do some basic logging of the execution times within the various classes, but I'm having a hard time figuring out how to do that.

The script itself contains four classes:

```
class Pull(luigi.Task):
class Validate(luigi.Task):
class Upload(luigi.Task):
class Finalize(luigi.Task):
```

Another script executes the `Finalize` class, and within that, in order for it to execute, the Upload class has to have finished, and for the Upload class to run, the Validate has to have finished, and for the Validate class to run, the Pull class has to have finished.  All of the classes are structured in this same manner:

```
class Finalize(luigi.Task):

    environment = luigi.Parameter(default='dev')

    def requires(self):
        return [Upload(environment=self.environment)]

    def output(self):
        return luigi.LocalTarget(f'.out/{CUR_DATE}_{self.environment}_Finalize.txt')

    def run(self):
        # ....code goes here
```

What I've tried is, outside of the classes, up at the top of the page is to set up some global variables: (I've also tried defining this code block within the Finalize class itself, AND within the `run` function of the Finalize class.  All 3 attempts yield the exact same thing that I explain below)

```
import time

global pull_time
global validate_time
global upload_time 
global finalize_time

pull_time   = 0
validate_time = 0
upload_time = 0
finalize_time = 0
```

Then within each of these classes, write data to the global var in question, like this, from the `Pull` function:

```
global pull_time 
pull_time = round(time.time() - self.start_time1, 2)
print(f"Time to pull = {pull_time}")
```

This seems to work, **locally within this class**, as it prints out `Time to pull = 11.42`, however my ultimate goal is to get all of these read by the `Finalize` class, so I can save the data into mysql and log it, but no matter what I try, I cannot seem to get these variables to have any value but `0` in the `Finalize` class, which currently prints out:

```
global finalize_time
finalize_time = round(time.time() - self.start_time4, 2)
print(f"Time to finalize = {finalize_time}")

print(f"all together now: pull = {pull_time}, validate = {validate_time}, upload = {upload_time}, finalize = {finalize_time}")

# all together now: pull = 0, validate = 0, upload = 0, finalize = 133
```

I am not putting `global pull_time` etc, within the `Finalize` class, as I am not modifying them - I just want their updated values, but I cannot figure out how to do that.

If there is another method by which I could pass this data in between classes, I would be fine doing that too - I don't have to do it with global variables.

Comment: `global` statements have to be put in the functions that assign the variables, not at top-level.

Comment: Yeah - I tried that (as I stated in the question), but I cannot get any value other than `0` to show for any of these variables, even if the globals are defined within that function

Comment: Then you need to post a [mre].

Comment: Put the `*_time` variables in their own module e. g. `timedata`. When you import it into another module, you can refer to a variable with e. g. `timedata.pull_time` for getting and setting.

Comment: Just for starters, you shouldn't be modifying global variables to begin with. This is the *whole point of classes*, to *encapsulate state*.

Comment: "Another script executes the Finalize class, " what do you mean another script? You are using multiple different processes? You really must provide a [mcve]